# How Windows routing works on application level?

Tags: windows, networking

Imagine I have Windows TCP socket. And the application connects this socket **once** on startup. And then **sends/receives TCP traffic for long time**.

Windows has ability to route IP traffic. Imagine you have multiple network adaptors and you have to set static routing for your application that the traffic goes to a particular NIC.

The question is - **will Windows waste CPU cycles to route TCP socket connection only or will it route every IP packet?**

I am counting microseconds and I need to know precisely - **will be there CPU overhead on sending / receiving the traffic or connection only** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "routing" you mean the process of looking at the local routing table to decide where an outgoing packet should be sent.  This is decided first by which router to use, and second which interface to use to get to that router.

If you have established a static route, "routing" must still occur for the system to see that route.  This consists of a table lookup which takes just a few dozen machine instructions.  It is absolutely negligible compared to the cost of copying the packet around.

Keep in mind that binding a socket to a network interface is not the same as entering static rules into the routing table, and that a network interface is not the same as a Network Interface Controller (NIC).  This is important when considering overhead, because the effect of binding or routing to a particular network interface, may be that the packet gets copied extra times which will create substantial overhead.

It is possible to contrive a scenario in which a packet is transmitted on the LAN, re-read by the same computer that transmitted it, then transmitted again through a different NIC to the correct router.  Most often, the best performance will be had by binding to `INADDR_ANY` (address `0.0.0.0`) and letting the routing tables handle the optimization for you.

Binding to a particular network interface should only be done if you need to ensure that a particular IP address is used for sending and receiving.  Static routing to a particular NIC seems unlikely to produce useful results unless the local routing is already broken in some way.  Otherwise, interfering with the normal routing process just risks adding to the overhead.

Comment: Seth thank you.. but it is much simpler. the key words in the question was "will Windows waste CPU cycles".. I meant exactly routing by Windows (not hardware router). And the static routing specifically. So the question is about - what Windows does during lifecycle of a TCP connected socket - does it 'route' (do some CPU work) on connecting the socket or does it 'route' each packet?

Comment: Windows (or any system with an IP stack) is a router.  The exact same things that go on in a network device also occur in an end-point node.  So yes, Windows does look at each packet and its routing table to figure out where it needs to go.  But the CPU work for doing that is negligible.  For a routing device on a network backbone, where the routing table may have millions of entries, it is much more substantial.  But for an end-node, even one with a few NICs, the table will be very small.

Comment: Thank you. negligible for 99.99% applications yes. not mine.